# Keycloak redirect flashing screen when switching between multiple frontends apps under one domain and using Okta as Idp

Tags: keycloak

**Background:**

I've 3 micro frontend react apps, one for each tab of my menu bar so every time I click on a different menu corresponding micro UI app is loaded.
For authentication I'm trying to use Keycloak. I use Keycloak JS adapter, created this in shared library and use it across 3 apps I have. Everything works fine until now.

**Problem:**

Next thing I did is in Keycloak admin server I added Okta as Idp, as soon as I did that what happens is when I switch between tabs, it flashes Okta redirect screen. This happens because
when I switch tab I load a different micro UI app which initializes keycloak behind the scene -> calls okta for verification(which is redirect flash) -> page loads. Now this redirect flash
doesn't look good when switching tabs in same website. Which is what I am trying to solve.

**What I've tried:**

1. Now to get rid of this Okta redirect flashing, what I did is I store
   the token in browser local storage as soon as I login for the very
   first time then when I click on different menu which loads my
   another micro UI app and here I check my local storage to see if
   there is token. If Yes -> don't initialize KC. If No -> initialize KC
   (meaning logging in for very first time)  The problem with this
   approach is my token never gets updated because I'm using KeycloakJS
   Callback method to update my token but since I didn't initialize kc after I switched to new menu(corresponding app) callback methods don't work.
2. After my first login when I switch tab I tried to do "check-sso"
   with silent login and still see Okta redirect.

So if I initialize KC every time I switch tab(i.e. every time I call new app) everything works fine but I don't like the redirect. If I don't initialize KC when I change tabs -> token doesn't get updated. I thought of merging all my micro frontend apps this will probably solve the problem but will break the reason I created micro front end apps.

I am new to using KC so any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: Is every micro frontend configured to be a dedicated client in Keycloak?

Comment: no I just created one client for frontend and all micro UI using same one

Comment: That's weird, cause Keycloak should not redirect to Okta if you have a valid session with Keycloak. Did you make any changes to the authentication flows?

Comment: yes I created a extra IDP redirect flow to use(which might be the issue? not sure). I am following this guide 
https://docs.hypr.com/installinghypr/docs/adding-okta-as-an-idp-in-keycloak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration from the guide that you have provided, enforces a redirect to Okta for every login via Keycloak. I do not think that there is any reason to do so. Try to add a cookie authenticator as an alternative in front of the identity provider redirect. That should skip the redirect to Okta once a session with Keycloak has been established.

[image: Authenticaton flow with cookie for SSO]

Edit:
If for any reasons you need to enforce that redirect to Okta (besides for the initial login), you may want to try to change the SAML binding to a redirect binding instead of a POST binding.